# Angular component does not refresh

Tags: angular

I try to refresh my component by selecting an item in a drop box

```
<select (change)="onChangePerPage($event.target.value)">
<option *ngFor="let perPage of perPages" [value]="perPage" [selected]="perPage===currentPerPage">{{ perPage }}</option>
</select>
```

the event that is triggered when selecting an item in the drop box will update this.currentPerPage

```
onChangePerPage(perPage)
{
    this.currentPerPage=perPage;
    this.updatePagesCount();
}
```

and will update this.nPages

```
updatePagesCount()
{
       this.nPages=Math.floor(this.settings.options.pagination.count/this.settings.options.pagination.current);
    if(this.settings.options.pagination.count % this.settings.options.pagination.current>0)
        this.nPages++;
}
```

and I expect this one to be updated based on nPages beeign modified :

```
<div *ngFor="let page of _.range(nPages)" (click)="gotoPage(page)" class="paginationPageDiv" [class.paginationActiveDiv]="page==currentPage">{{ page+1 }}</div>
```

but nothing in the component gets refreshed

please help